# How can i change the size of the buttons of my options menu?

Tags: android, options-menu

I have an options menu (it pops up when you press the menu key of the phone) with 5 buttons, all of them with one 48x48 image and text.

Now the five buttons are displayed in two rows, but I want to reduce the size of them to fit all five buttons into one row.

How can I achieve this?

Can I do it with parameters in the menu's layout XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the menu is using a standard layout of max three buttons next to each other, to make it tough friendly if you read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html it says you can add max 6 menu items in the normal menu after that they will move into the extended menu, so 3 items per line total of 6 items on two lines. It's just how Android is designed.

Comment: as far as the Android Documentation goes yes. You could always try to manually overwrite the options menu feature and roll your own but that would probably be more effort that it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100 percent sure what you mean? But you might be able to achieve what you want with margin and padding?

Padding would increase the size of your button